# How to calculate the stroke rate of a rowing boat using an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gyroscope

I would like to know the best way to attack calculating the stroke rate of a person rowing in an actual row boat. I would like to know what sensors would be best for measuring the typical boat acceleration cycle encountered in rowing, or is there a better way of approaching such a event.

I figure I have to worry about X,Y,Z axis of the phone as its on the boat. So ignore the Z axis and only worry about X or Y depending how the phone is positioned on the boat.

What sensors or frameworks should I use to measure such a movement?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know what sensors would be best for measuring the typical boat acceleration cycle encountered in rowing.

As you know, a rowing shell doesn't move through the water at a constant rate, but rather accelerates and decelerates as the rowers move through the stroke. Assuming that the device is in the boat, you could certainly use the accelerometer to measure these forces and determine the stroke rate. You'd probably want to look at the signal and find some easy-to-identify point in the stroke, and then measure the time between such points. For example, it shouldn't be hard to find the point of inflection where the boat stops decelerating and begins accelerating, which should correspond roughly to the catch.

The microphone is another sensor that might work. Oars make a distinctive sound when they turn in the oarlocks as the rowers feather the blades. As long as the rowers are rowing together, you could probably process the audio and measure the time between those sounds.

A much easier technique would be to simply have the coxswain (you wouldn't leave the dock without a coxswain, right?) tap a button on screen at every catch or every finish. That's not practical if you want to monitor the rate over a long period, but it'd let the cox determine the rate when needed.

Comment: awesome, nice reply gives me some points to work from.. I have writen a few business applications but nothing using any of the sensors in the phone which I find more intresting and exciting so now i can venture forth and discover some cool stuff hopefully! lol

Comment: So Have just done some perliminary reading, fount that I will need to use the CoreMotion framework to access the Accelerometer. I was woundering to get an accurate stroke algoritum, I would have to measure a 3 y axis variables at seperate times to sense the change in force? that would represent a stroke..

Comment: @HurkNburkS 40 strokes per *minute* is an example of a very high stroke rate. You can get accelerometer samples at a much higher rate. 40 samples per *second* isn't unreasonable, and would give you 60+ samples per stroke even at high rates. That should be more than enough to accurately determine the stroke rate. With each sample you'll get an instance of `CMAccelerometerData`, which has measurements for all three axes. Depending on how you fix the device in the boat, you could get away with looking at just one axis.